# How does Entity Framework Core implement code first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-core-2.1

I’m trying to learn how Entity Framework core uses C# classes to create the DbContext model. I assume it discovers types based on DbSets then calls the same model builder that is passed to OnSchemaCreating, I just can’t find the code/logic in the repository that does this (or perhaps there is another approach). Can anyone explain how this is done and point to the source code that does this?

Comment: [EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore), Also "how does this work" questions aren't really the best fit for this site really.

Comment: I mentioned I can’t find the code in the repository, so a link to it doesn’t really help. Also, the question is clearly about a library/tool - so it is on-topic, and the question doesn’t fall in any of the “doesn’t belong here” categories (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

[Smit Patel](https://github.com/smitpatel) from the ASP.NET team [pointed me to the answer](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13134#issuecomment-416462673). There is a `ModelSource` abstraction that takes both a `DbContext` as well as some conventions. It customizes the the model based on `DbSet`s on the `DbContext` class by simply adding an entity type for each `DbSet`, the remaining property/key/index configurations are all done by conventions.